# Android Swipe View help needed

Tags: java, android

I have a swipe `Activity`, with 2 swipe pages, I added the content for the first page and on the second page the content is duplicated, how can I set different content to the second page in my swipe view?

```
public class ListItemClicked extends ActionBarActivity {

static Bundle extras;

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
static ImageLoader imageLoader;
static DisplayImageOptions options;

ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item_clicked);



    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(config);

    //Setup options for ImageLoader so it will handle caching for us.
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .build();



}


   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}


public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_item_clicked, container, false);


        TextView pDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        pDate.setText( extras.getString("pdate") );


        TextView ptitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        ptitle.setText(extras.getString("pname"));


        TextView pnText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        pnText.setText( extras.getString("pText"));

        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Developers site really has very good explanation of ViewPager. You should check it out:
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Here is an example I wrote:

activity_screen_slide.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Java Code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
...

public class ScreenSlidePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            //Create these fragments with your preferable names
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new ScreenSlidePageFragment2();
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is one of your views that should look like it where fragment_ screen_slide_page is one of your layouts:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
...

public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

You should really read the android developers site for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You can return different fragments like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    } else {
        return anotherFragment.newInstance();
    }
}
```

If you want to use the same `Fragment`, you can change the content depending on the position you are passing to the fragment.

Comment: newInstance(position + 1) what is the scope of the parameter of the function?

Comment: As you have new instance of fragment in the fragment class depending on that no you can change the content