# PagerAdapter issue with android Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-pageradapter

I have one issue with PagerAdapter in which when i load `TextView` in it it works perfectly code is below:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvtest);
    tv.setText("" + position);

    container.addView(view);
    return view;
}
```

**But** when i use a `Fragment` instead of `TextView` like in below code `PagerAdapter` is only loading first fragment.
Please help me to solve this problem.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment ();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = mActivity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();

    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}
```

**XML code:**

**When using TextView**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tvtest"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Test"
android:textSize="30sp" />
```

**When using Fragment**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485848/how-load-fragment-in-viewpager-only-when-its-selected

Comment: Sorry i am not using FragmentPagerAdapter  in my question im using PagerAdapter

Comment: You may need to check ViewPager tutorial here. It may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32072274/4843993

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use FragmentPagerAdapter instead of PagerAdapter.

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
            return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
        case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
            return FirstFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
        case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
            return SecondFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + position;
    }

}
```